# What is the use of "Attach to Autoscaling Group" in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, ec2-ami, launch-configuration

I'm sorry if it feels like a dumb question to you.But I have to know this.

**What is the use of "Attach to Auto-scaling Group" in AWS?**

Let me be more specific about this question.

Suppose I have an auto-scaling group with a launch configuration. Lets name it 
*ABC-asg* I used *ami-12345* for that launch configuration. 
Now I have another instance from *ami-56789*. Lets name my instance *xyz* and I've installed some packages in it.
I attached my instance *xyz* to the autoscaling group ABC-asg.But the new instances launched by that asg are using *ami-12345.*

My questions are

1.What is the use of attaching my instance to an existing auto-scaling group?

2.If it is about the "different *ami*" in my instance. So if I attach an instance with "same *ami*" will my packages replicated to the next instances launched by the asg?

Please someone help me with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Attach to Auto-scaling Group** simply adds the given instance to the Auto Scaling group. This means the instance will be part of the group of instances that can receive traffic from a Load Balancer associated with the group and it also means that Auto Scaling might Terminate the instance when scaling-in a group.

The only different between an instance attached to an Auto Scaling group in this manner is that it was not created by Auto Scaling.

So, why have such a command? Here's a few scenarios:

- You have a new version of software or a different server configuration that you wish to **test**. You can **attach** the instance to the Auto Scaling group and monitor its performance without having to update the whole group.
- You have an instance in an Auto Scaling group that is **misbehaving**. You can remove it from the group with the **Detach Instances** command and examine the instance to perform forensic analysis to determine what is going wrong. You could then put it back into the group with the **Attach Instances** command.
- AWS customers asked for the ability

Attaching/detaching an instance in no way affects your Launch Configuration. Any additional instances launched by Auto Scaling will not be impacted by an attach/detach command -- they will launch using the existing Launch Configuration.